# Randomized String Searching

Tags: algorithms, strings, searching, probabilistic-algorithms

I need to detect whether a binary pattern $P$ of length $m$ occurs in a binary text $T$ of length $n$ where $m < n$.

I want to state an algorithm that runs in time $O(n)$ where we assume that arithmetic operations on $O(\log_2 n)$ bit numbers can be executed in constant time. The algorithm should accept with probability $1$ whenever $P$ is a substring of $T$ and reject with probability of at least $1 - \frac{1}{n}$ otherwise.

I think fingerprinting could help here. But I can't get it.

Comment: What is a binary pattern? What does it mean for P to occur in T? (I can think of _some_ definitions but providing a reference will probably help.)

Comment: KMP is good (and already mentioned). [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) works even faster if properly implemented (see [here](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html)).

Comment: The term you want to Wikipedia for is [string searching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_matching) (or matching).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) does this in linear time without any error.

Comment: But it runs in time $O(n+m)$ which is not equal to $O(n)$ if the pattern is not fixed!

Comment: @Raphael: The question says $m<n$.

Comment: @Raphael: Also, if $m>n$, you can just return FALSE immediately.